# server name on local machine

Tags: xpages

## Environment

I develop Xpages applications locally using Lotus Domino Designer as a web server, but for browser, not for Notes client.

## Problem

I have not found a solution for search in another database using **@DbLookup/@DbColumn**, because I do not know how to define the server part:

1. **""** does not seems working in case of browser
2. **database.getServer()** returns my Lotus Notes username, which also does not seems to work

## Question

What **formula/SSJS code** can be used for getting the proper servername?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This reads from a local database (all usernames from your local names and address book):

```
var dbname = new Array("", "names.nsf");
@DbColumn(dbname, "($Users)", 1);
```

=> so the server is specified as empty string (""). 
A very common mistake that is made is that the ACL of local databases must grant anonymous reader access (because you access with an anonymous http session).
Can you check that first?

Comment: Thank you. Anonymous access causes problems, and it should be evident.